# Graph API vs own app home feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to fetch the endpoint `/me/home` from the Facebook graph API v2.1.

Using the Graph API Explorer tool, I get good results that look like what the facebook mobile app displays. But when I switch to my app and simulate the exact same call with the exact same permissions, the results are different and include a lot of non relevant posts (such as "ARandomFriend liked a link").

The only difference beetween the two calls is the access token (same scope, same permissions, same user). My guess is that facebook voluntarily returns a less relevant feed to third party apps so that people can't build apps that can compete with them.

But maybe I'm wrong, does anyone know something about this ?

Comment: I'm using the Graph API for both calls, the only difference is the origin of the call. The first is from the Graph API explorer, the second is from my app. For both I'm asking for a user token for my own facebook user with specific permissions and once I get it, I call /me/home to retrieve the newsfeed. And on the second call I get a lot more "junk". I insist on the fact that I'm calling the graph api both times.

Comment: I actually get different results from what shows in my news feed compared to the explorer.

Comment: This question is not relevant anymore, seems like facebook is now preventing devs to use the read_stream permission so it will no longer be possible to get the newsfeed. As described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540854/facebook-graph-api-read-stream-permission-actually-blocked-for-non-facebook-bran)

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to

[Some posts not visible on the feed through Graph API /me/home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533773/some-posts-not-visible-on-the-feed-through-graph-api-me-home/26552242?noredirect=1#comment41760752_26552242)

and

[Facebook SDK for .NET and Graph API Explorer news feed mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589664/facebook-sdk-for-net-and-graph-api-explorer-news-feed-mismatch/26590438?noredirect=1#comment41795993_26590438)

The reason is Facebook "scores" nodes to derive the most "Top Story". Low scoring nodes are by default not visible. You can force all nodes with

```
/me/home.filter(owner)<some_filters like fields requests>
```

There is no documentation on WHY this actually works, but it does. You can also force all nodes that are Likes or Comments by doing the following

```
me/posts?fields=likes.filter(stream),comments.filter(stream)
```

Comment: I actually get more results from my app than when using the graph api explorer. What I mean is that my results is not "junk filtered". When I get a post like "Frank likes a link" via my app I can't do anything with it as it doesn't have any usefull displayable informations. Just that someone liked something. When I use the explorer, such results just don't show up. But thanks for your help anyway, as I said, the read_stream permission cannot be used anymore.