# Some posts not visible on the feed through Graph API /me/home

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an application and I've noticed that some posts from the feed are not visible through Graph API /me/home. But if I send request from Graph API Explorer app, I could see.

For example
Request from my app http://storage9.static.itmages.com/i/14/1023/h_1414085047_2753961_8f3284c6bd.png

Request from Graph API Explorer
http://storage7.static.itmages.com/i/14/1023/h_1414084999_5837075_594eb48230.png

Permissions are identical

What could be the problem?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483437/graph-api-vs-own-app-home-feed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go.

```
me?fields=home.filter(others){message,id}
```

FB's documentation is horrible.

Comment: do you know, what are the values for filter?

Comment: In this case with the "home" field it's the same values that are used in FQL, "owner" and "others".   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/home/    You can also use filter on comments and likes fields but the values become "toplevel" or "stream" https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/object/comments/

Comment: Looks like with v2.2 they have changed the syntax of this call...now it looks like you may have to use this `me/home?filter=owner`

Comment: I have the same problem with my application but your suggested solution doesn't seem to do it.

I compared the Newsfeed on the Facebook website (home_FB) with the Newsfeed in the Graph API Explorer (home_API):

A [/me?fields=home]: ~80% of the stories in home_FB are missing in home_API, but all stories in home_API eventually turn up further down in home_FB.

B [/me?fields=home.filter(others)]: I get way more stories in home_API but neither of these (mostly "user shared/liked X" etc) are shown anywhere on home_FB. I also don't get any of the stories from home_FB that were missing in A.