# FB.api('/me/home') only returns a few results

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting the results of the `/me/home` Facebook Graph edge.  But it's only returning a few results, as compared with the way my News feed looks when I go to Facebook.  Code here:

```
FB.api('/me/home',function(response){
            var idDiv=document.getElementById('result');
            idDiv.textContent=JSON.stringify(response.data);
            });
```

For me, this only returns 16 results.  I'm wondering if the results are based on the permissions that my friends have set regarding who can read their posts.  However, some of the results that are returned have the "shared with friends" permission, and some have the "public" permission.  What determines which stories are returned with this query?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to.

[Some posts not visible on the feed through Graph API /me/home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533773/some-posts-not-visible-on-the-feed-through-graph-api-me-home/26552242?noredirect=1#comment41760752_26552242)

and

[Facebook SDK for .NET and Graph API Explorer news feed mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589664/facebook-sdk-for-net-and-graph-api-explorer-news-feed-mismatch/26590438?noredirect=1#comment41795993_26590438)

The reason is Facebook "scores" nodes to derive the most "Top Story". Low scoring nodes are by default not visible. You can force all nodes with

```
/me/home.filter(owner)<some_filters>
```

There is no documentation on WHY this actually works, but it does. You can also force all nodes that are Likes or Comments by doing the following

```
me/posts?fields=likes.filter(stream),comments.filter(stream)
```

Comment: What do I put in for `owner`?  I tried both `FB.api('/me/home.filter(owner)')` and `FB.api('/me/home.filter('12345235')` using my user ID number, and neither returned any results.

Comment: Looks like with v2.2 they have changed the syntax of this call...now it looks like you'll have to use this `me/home?filter=owner` The values you can use for filter is `owner` and `others` but there seems to be no difference in the results returned. These are the values filter used with FQL. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/home Also the max value of limit mentioned above is 250 not 200.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the syntax.  I'm still missing most of my news feed, only getting posts from band pages, political advocacies, etc.  Do you think my friends' privacy settings are preventing their status updates from being included in this call's results?

Comment: I notice I'm not seeing posts via the API that are a friend sharing a post of some page/user I am not directly connected too (liked or friend). It looks like the bug may be tracked and being worked on. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/576745515760299/

Comment: The Facebook Team confirmed that this bug is being tracked, but it's a different issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/675008585946360/

Answer (score -1):

You can get the number of post to display using **limit** parameter. Eg,

***me?fields=id,name,posts.limit(25)***

Gives only 25 post per API hit. If you need to get more post, You need to set count limit in **limit** parameter. Also note that, you can retrieve only 200 post per API hit. i.e. You can set maximum of **200** in your **limit** parameter and you get your recent number of post.

You can use, **Next** url in API to get next set of feeds. Like,

"next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/778783212329364/posts?limit=25&until=1414386975"

To get next set of post and you can merge this with your first list. You can't get all the post in single API hit and this is how you can achieve.

Comment: The OP is looking to retrieve his entire "News Feed" not just the posts (s)he has made. Using `me?fields=id,name,posts.limit(25)` will only get the posts. Even using `feed` in place of `posts`will only get the post (s)he has made aggregated with posts other users have made to (s)he's feed. The `home` edge will return all the posts (s)he sees in Facebook, this includes the same items as `feed` aggregated with the posts pages (s)he has liked and posts in groups (s)he is apart of.  Also the max value for limit is 250