# Facebook Graph API read_stream permission actually blocked for non-Facebook branded apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, deprecated, facebook-permissions

Getting some conflicting information from Facebook currently on whether or not the read_stream permission is actually deprecated for non-Facebook branded apps moving forward. I know recently the change was made to require app-specific access tokens for read-stream permissions.

In the Facebook graph explorer it looks as though my existing application which was already granted an app-specific access token for the read_stream persmission is still providing access to the [user-id]/posts endpoint, although I also noticed that searching for this endpoint in the reference takes you now to [user-id]/feed, which also requires the read_stream permission.

When searching the read_stream permission in the [reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-read_stream) however, it now reads:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop and TV apps will not be granted this permission.
>   Blockquote

Wondering if anyone from Facebook or outside can actually confirm that this endpoint is now closed to 3rd-party apps, and if there is any explanation whatsoever for why?

Comment: You can use it for 3rd-party app if you are creating a Facebook-branded client on a platform where Facebook is not already available

Comment: So you have to create a whole new client before you can use it, and then you still need to get their permission and brand it as Facebook..unless you're creating the next android with Facebook's permission, it's essentially it's walled up for every 3rd-party.

Comment: Did a little bit more research and it looks like although the [user-id]/feed endpoint is effected by this permission redaction, the [page-id]/feed endpoint requires no read_stream permission, so you can still get the post level data from pages.

Comment: Hi Dante, did you find out more about that? Judging from Facebook's statement there is no change to get read_stream approved. Or is there?

Comment: No, as far as I know Facebook has no intention of bringing the option to gain the read_stream permission back. It looks as though it's sealed shut.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an effort to get rid of third-party apps, which is a shame. I can't stand their official app. Had been developing a third-party client on and off for a couple years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now someone can use "**user_posts**" permission - This new permission allows an app to access the posts on a person's Timeline. This includes the someone's own posts, posts they are tagged in and posts other people make on their Timeline. 
This is a useful alternative to News Feeds.
Previously, this content was accessible with the read_stream permission. The user_posts permission is automatically granted to anyone who previously had read_stream permission.

[Facebook Platform Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

Comment: I don't think so that the "User_posts" permission can be granted by default  incase of "read_stream" is already granted.since Facebook has already mentioned there are only three permissions like "Email","public_profile" and "user_friends" can be accessed by default.