# Facebook SDK for .NET and Graph API Explorer news feed mismatch

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

And application is using facebook sdk to get user newsfeed via `client.Get(request_string)` where `request_string = "/me/home<some_filters>"`. And I discovered that sdk and api exprorer return different results with the same request string. Why can it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to this question.

[Some posts not visible on the feed through Graph API /me/home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533773/some-posts-not-visible-on-the-feed-through-graph-api-me-home/26552242?noredirect=1#comment41760752_26552242)

The reason is Facebook "scores" nodes to derive the most "Top Story". Low scoring nodes are by default not visible. You can force all nodes with

```
/me/home.filter(owner)<some_filters>
```

There is no documentation on WHY this actually works, but it does. You can also force all nodes that are Likes or Comments by doing the following

```
me/posts?fields=likes.filter(stream),comments.filter(stream)
```

Comment: Facebook documentation makes me crazy sometimes. Thank you!

Comment: Agreed, they will deprecate FQL shortly and have horrible graph 2.1  documentation with no way to contact them.

Comment: Looks like with v2.2 they have changed the syntax of this call...now it looks like you may have to use this `me/home?filter=owner`

Comment: @FrankD `filter=owner` seems to return the news ticker stream (top-right on desktop), rather than the actual news feed. FWIW, `filter=lf` also returns the news ticker, and `filter=nf` or not using filter at all seems to return what looks like it could be top stories but the content still doesn't match facebook.com.